# Retrying @GenericGenerator on ConstraintViolationException

Tags: hibernate, spring-data

I am handling composite primary key creation with `@GenericGenerator`. In case of concurrent calls it sometimes fails with `ConstraintViolationException`. I would prefer to put a retry mechanism in place rather than fail some of my concurrent POST calls. The problem is I have not been able to force *re-generation* of the key.

I have tried calling `JpaRepository#saveAndFlush` again with the same object upon failure but the `@Id` stays the same once it has been generated.

Is there a common way to **retrigger `@Id` generation** for an entity upon `ConstraintViolationException`?

My entity definition:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "some_entity")
public class SomeEntity {

    @Embeddable
    public static class SomeEntityId implements Serializable {

        private int year;
        private int number;

        // (...)
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @GenericGenerator(name = "some_entity_id", strategy = "SomeEntityIdGenerator")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "some_entity_id")
    private SomeEntityId id;

    // (...)
}
```

The generator:

```java
public class SomeEntityIdGenerator implements IdentifierGenerator {

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
                                 Object object) throws HibernateException {

        int year = getYear(object);
        int number = getNumber(year, session.connection());

        return new SomeEntity.SomeEntitytId(year, number);
    }

    private static int getNumber(int year, Connection connection) {
        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(
                    "select max(request_number) from some_entity where year = ?");
            statement.setInt(1, year);

            ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery();

            if (rs.next()) {
                int max = rs.getInt(1);
                return max + 1;
            }

            return 1;

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new HibernateException(e);
        }
    }

    // (...)
}
```

Comment: SELECTing max(...) to get a new PID for an insert is a well-known RDBMS anti-pattern.  Just don't do it.   Hate to "X/Y" you on this but that "fix" you are asking for is really, really tortured.   (I would not accept code from a contractor where I found this!)

Comment: (since you want a unique integer key, perhaps you also want to separate out the "year" data into a separate column and just let the default pid generator - which will do the generation correctly/atomically - handle the pid...)

Comment: (it looks like you've /already/ got the year in a separate column!)